# Updating an image when select list changed

Tags: javascript

Well I've created a select list and I've added some countries . When the visitor choose a country the map of it appear .

The problem is when I finished I found the javascript code doesn't work ! It works when I use "setinterval" like this :

```
var ThisInterval = setInterval('maketime()',0);
 function maketime(){
  var Cvalue = $('#Country').val(); // ID for select menu
   $('#Country').click(function(){
    if(Cvalue == "USA"){
     $("#Countrymap").attr('src',"images/maps/USA.jpg");
  }
 }
 )};
```

we don't have to put all countries here , now is this code will make the browsing slow ? or I can use it ? if I can't then which way is the best ?

Comment: there is no replacement

Comment: It makes no sense to use set interval like that. We can't tell why the code doesn't work without it (although I have my suspicions) without more context. You need to provide a [real test case](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean, "visitor choose a country"? Is it a button click? What do you mean, "doesn't work"? See [mcve]

Comment: My question is clear . When the visitor choose a country from the select list the div which has an id called "Countrymap" will bring the map for the selected country .

Comment: my code dosen't work without setInterval and that's my problem

Comment: @Revolution — You haven't shown us enough of the code to tell why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all the javascript you need. Nothing else, no intervals, nothing!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Country').change(function(){
        var Cvalue = $('#Country').val();
        if(Cvalue == "USA"){
            $("#Countrymap").attr('src',"images/maps/USA.jpg");
        }
    });
});
```

---

If your image names match your select values, then you don't need an if/else chain at all, just use this:

```
var Cvalue = $('#Country').val();
$("#Countrymap").attr('src',"images/maps/" + Cvalue + ".jpg");
```

(obviously still inside the change event)

Comment: Sir you are absolutely brilliant , thanks so much :) @musefan